# Postfix and Apache: Permission denied on CentOS 7

Tags: apache-httpd, postfix, selinux

I am setting up a CentOS 7 Server with Apache2, MySQL, PHP and Postfix (for sending emails over PHP)

My problem at the moment is that I get the following error (at the error_log from Apache):

```
sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
```

The file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` has the following permissions: `-rw-r--r-- (622)`

The directory `/etc/postfix` has the following permissions: `drwxr-xr-x (755)`

The owner of this directory is `root`.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Why would Apache need to write to that file?  Did you modify anything in /etc/postfix without running a make?

Comment: Are you serious that /etc/postfix/main.cf is a directory?

Comment: I did not modify /etc/postfix.

Comment: /etc/postfix/main.cf is a file, I know ;)

Comment: Do you expect to send mail without configuring postfix?  What is the most recent file in /etc/postfix?  What are you trying to do when you get that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to adjust SELinux policy to allow apache to send mail. Easiest way is to turn on *httpd_can_sendmail* boolean <sup>[[1](https://selinuxproject.org/page/ApacheRecipes#Allow_the_Apache_HTTP_Server_to_send_mail)]</sup>.

```
semanage boolean -m --on httpd_can_sendmail
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot guy! - Have I to make some other important settings?

Comment: No other adjustments are necessary if the specific boolean sovles your issue. You might find the documentation ([`man httpd_selinux`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-httpd_selinux/#lbAF)) useful if you need to make other adjustments.

Comment: It solved my problem too. I was having problem of sending email using PHP `mail()` function.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd need 755 permissions on the child-items of the folder as well.
as for postfix is not in the root-group.

```
chmod -Rf 755 /etc/postfix
```

Comment: Did you mean -R  ?   Or did you hide the error messages on purpose?

Comment: -R you're right, sry^^

Comment: You'd better edit your reply, allthough  I don't know if /etc/postfix has subfolders.  The error isn't referring to a subfolder though, main.cf is a file, not a "direction".